# Dynamic Content: How to adjust div's position automatically?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am setting up a single html page, in which the content changes dynamically based on API calls.Depending on the content length, almost every time a new API call is made, the whole css does not work anymore and divs start to overlap each other. Is there anyway to position the elements dynamically based on the positon of the previous element?

The code's structure is something like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
        <p class="content">Dynamic content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <p class="content">I am getting overlapped!</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
width: 70%;
padding-top: 40px;
position: relative;
left: 123px;
} 

.div1 {
width: 80%;
top: 180px;
position: absolute;
}

.div2 {
position: absolute;
top: 380px;
width: 70%;
padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

I would be very thankful if someone knows a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like you should not be using `position: absolute`. The default element positioning is `static` which will position elements in the normal document flow, so that your `.div2` will follow your `.div1` (even when the length of your dynamic content changes). Try removing all of the `position` lines from your css to see what I mean.

Comment: thank you! I just changed  `.container` to `position: absolute` and `.div1` &  `.div2` to `position: relative` and it fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

you can add `top:0;` in the upper div example add `top:0;` in div1

```
.div1 {
width: 80%;
position: absolute;
background:black;
top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use any grid system that control the any dynamic changes in changes in your web pages.
**https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/**
Try this. this will make your web page responsive.